# Laravel 5 with homestead having unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

Hi I am using `Laravel 5` with `homestead`. I am experiencing `homestead` first time so facing problem. I have created a database 'myDb' and imported data into this. I have installed `vagrant` and `homestead`, cloned my code and configured `homestead.yaml` file accordingly. I have set up my `.env`. When I try to run my project is is giving me `unknown database myDb error`. I can see my database in my `phpmyadmin` but I do not know why it is giving me this error. My `.env` file looks like

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=myDb
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

And I have same settings in my `config/database.php` too.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'myDb'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
```

Its really making me mad. What Am I doing wrong? I am getting following

```
  in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb', 'homestead',   'secret', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in Connector.php line 55
at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'myDb', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in MySqlConnector.php line 22
 at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'myDb', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 60
at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'myDb', 'username' => 'homestead', 'password' => 'secret', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 49
```

Comment: Have you updated your `config/database.php` file ?

Comment: Yes. I have updated that too

Comment: It's maybe caching issue, are u restart webserver

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` what you are getting on `connector.php` file `createConnection` function , if It is not getting things correctly ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Done

Comment: Are you getting same error and the output you have post ? Is there any chance of port problem, if you have changed and forgotten ? beside this nothing coming to my mind if database is created .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One common mistake that you might be making is that you're probably accessing MySQL server on your localhost while you should remember that Homestead is a complete virtual dev. environment. It has it's own Web Server, MySQL server and etc.

To see if you have "myDB" on the Homestead MySQL server as well, try accessing homestead via the following command.

```
homestead ssh
```

Once done that, try opening the mysql console via the mysql command.

```
mysql -u username -p
```

And after that list all your databases using

```
show databases
```

If you can't see "myDb" database there, than you should try connecting to Homestead MySQL server using Navicat or MySQL Workbench and move your database from your local MySQL server to the Homestead MySQL server.

That would probably fix your problem.

Comment: Hey man... This is what I was looking for.. Thank you. +1 for nice explanation

Comment: No problem! Do let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are migrating your database, check if you are migrating the same database name inside your `Homestead.yaml` file and the database name in your `.env` file.

Inside `Homestead.yaml` file:

```yaml
databases:
    - laravel
```

Inside your `.env` file:

```
DB_DATABASE=laravel
```